# Verify an array of fixed-length character strings is sorted at compile time

Tags: c++, sorting, c-strings, constexpr, static-assert

When trying to verify an array of fixed-length character strings is sorted at compile time, there is odd behavior in using `strncmp`.

If the validation function references the global array, all values of N seem to work.

```cpp
#include <cstring>

#define N 8 // vary values of N

const char STRINGS[][N] = {"a", "b", "c"};

constexpr bool is_sorted_global() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(STRINGS) / N - 1; i++) {
        if (strncmp(STRINGS[i], STRINGS[i + 1], N) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    // always works for any N
    static_assert(is_sorted_global(), "list is not sorted");
}
```

However, if using a function template, only values where N is less than or equal to 8 seem to work.

```cpp
template<const char T[][N]>
constexpr bool is_sorted_t() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(T) / N - 1; i++) {
        if (strncmp(T[i], T[i+1], N) > 0) {
            return false;
        } 
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    // only works for N <= 8
    static_assert(is_sorted_t<STRINGS>(), "list not sorted");
}
```

For example, with N = 9, the template approach will error with...

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp -o C:\Projects\helloworld\helloworld.exe

C:\Projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp:34:39: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   34 |     static_assert(is_sorted_t<STRINGS>(), "list is not sorted");
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
C:\Projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp:34:39:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'is_sorted_t<(& STRINGS)>()'
C:\Projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp:23:25: error: 'strncmp(((const char*)(& STRINGS)), (((const char*)(& STRINGS)) + 9), 9)' is not a constant expression
   23 |         if (std::strncmp(T[i], T[i + 1], N) > 0) {
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Unfortunately for me, I need N to equal 16 and I have multiple global STRINGS arrays to verify, so I was hoping the function template would allow me to check each one with static assertion.

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCBAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8YF2mA7pQgRMxASZPn5cFZj2BQy19QRFkTFxCbZ1DU3ZrcM9fSVlCQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BYcjeWADUJv5uyAoExGHAB9gmGgCC13dm/lg04bsRu1wAbLsA9D%2B7ADd6gBPN6kXYAd0ICF2BAQmF2wFQYl2qCobwOABEvvd7icmI5kLs0AwTsSEPVdkIACoAJQAkhEAOJCEwAVisbMx7IsEXZmP2/gFJgA7FYzGYmOYzODpdFpbKJaYJaLuf4rLd7iSTphVIliLtoqhPLs8AoAPoKEgETDoc3AWioaJiCBzfZi%2B67L27fgGiBhAimwUCjQHCxBg5uXapABemDREBpDOZQjd/3eAFoPmHTdZrG7RRqbt6S6b0RATsQGMgWIlE3TGSyeXh%2BeCk43WRy8PtLNmueCIgX/NhdhoCx7bqWp7tiJgCMsGD6xEow57p6q116N5rJ97Z/Oq7DiF5MKvNSLuTubjbawYbZHtYHkBSDdSefyeXyuZctQIdXqDSNE0zUta1bXNAhXXdIsS19XZ/UECMhVHHNu0jaM8DjBNqTTN5dizLhULzSxxxg6c8HLStq1rCA3y7Vtdjoiw0N7Qj%2BzeIcRzHaDN2nL19wXJdaBXdVeJLVV9l3LcL1xKSZznQTThPM87hkq8A12FgmDCV1cQnYtvXxQlzSYBQlAaf0LStBpwIdJ0XQWHszFoM1AzNXYGFQQNrJtdBpTmHM/khEgAGsFB9EhdkMUE%2BTkoy8GQEyzLiSCQJ88CCEjdsU0uV1FWc1zTXCzzvLAvyJQC9Vfn%2BCFQvCgRaFBOD3kjLFdgADlkgz%2BIUw9Q1E89MQ4BZaE4NleD8DgtFIVBODcYjwytZZVh7fweFIAhNGGhYQpAMwRQAOg0dqzE%2BSR/H2z5Pn8ABOEV2s%2BfROEkCatpmzheAUEANA2raFjgWAkDQWs6DichKGBxJQfiYAFGYRIFAQLzSCwAEEswAA1PBMAhAB5RJGE4daaFoG1iC%2BiBoje6IwhBIneBp5hiGBXHom0KpNu4XhgbYQRcYYRq3qwLSjHEKbeHwWdqgBTAvvFoJVCqLwbXp8hBHaVWXOiYgQQ8LBVdOPAWD%2BvgDFhrGcfxwmuZkQQRDEdgpFt%2BQlDUN7dC4fRDGMBb9DwaIvsgBZUESTo5YzXH/Hwk4/KFZVxQsLgRU%2B9oOfSFwGHcTxmj0EIwn6UpBk9vI0gEMYWlyFJS4YaYBniT3KmqARulGbPxlsVOm66EZenzmYi8mVusgr/EGlrwv64WJaVkdkaxte%2BXZo4XZVAejMzsRZAiQgJSGBCt0IFwQhIo2Lg5l4TmtDmBZ4SYLB4jy3bHgOi6uC%2BNkNHOkURTWtkno4F6pBJrTSXp9b6v1xb/RgIgFAqAQb0DIBQCAkNoYoAMEYCCx494o0wGjVYFs8YE0msTOgZMKZU3lozOmNsqHM1ZuzBwqseaMAIPzQW8thbezFutSWacZZy2mrqJWKsbYBg1jbLWOtmZ6zWOtQ2xtIGmyYObbGhDrbE1kPbcQTt%2BCCEUCodQ8tdAynQT7Sw1g/YB3gMHUO6Rw6R2jgQWOmJ47WCTinDo6cICuHLrnTO49ZjFyrp0XxQT8jpACQPRunQW6NDbiPTuMSe6RProPOJw89Cj17sUOuEgp5LBnnk/%2B40gFvSXivNeG9tje3grvfe8Ej5EANKfc%2BECr47T2pIA6bIbqfC4DdL4IobpsnaiKDQnw/6jQAbwY2XANA/WAbwUBthwGX2GqQAGMClgEESMrcGyC4FQwQREVgaxV6fHXpITe286mtNtMfM46A9C6OEKIbR0gXn6LdkYvQEIdaJHpnPDgJTFnvQ4LjZWuzAxogqRcjewAt61KwfUiAHh4FxFWmfC%2Bf0OlmEmc9BeICPorJ%2Bms6%2B/8zCEqWcSslCwZbk3TpIIAA)

Comment: I'm sorry if you saw my earlier comment, I was confused. It's unusual to see a 2D array of char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this won't answer the question of why your compiler behaves that way for the function template, here is a solution you can use. Pass the array as a function argument instead of template parameter as follows:

```
template<size_t Size, size_t Len>
constexpr bool is_sorted(const char (&arr)[Size][Len]) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < Size; i++) {
        if (strncmp(arr[i-1], arr[i], Len) > 0) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

This combines the benefits of template expansion with your working "global" approach. It also relaxes the dependency on the macro `N`.

```
static_assert(is_sorted(STRINGS), "list is not sorted");
```

That at least works with your compiler, although as pointed out in another answer `strncmp` is not actually a `constexpr`. This works in GCC but not Clang.

To correct this, a simple modification is to define your own `constexpr` string comparison and also make your array `constexpr`:

```
#include <cstddef>

#define N 16

constexpr char STRINGS[][N] = {"a", "b", "c"};

constexpr int my_strncmp(const char *a, const char *b, size_t n) {
    int delta = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
        do {
            delta = (int)(unsigned char)*a
                  - (int)(unsigned char)*b;
        } while (delta == 0 && *a++ && *b++ && --n != 0);
    }
    return delta;
}

template<size_t Size, size_t Len>
constexpr bool is_sorted(const char (&arr)[Size][Len]) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < Size; i++) {
        if (my_strncmp(arr[i-1], arr[i], Len) > 0) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}

static_assert(is_sorted(STRINGS), "list is not sorted");
```

Answer (score 5):

`strncmp` and even `std::strncmp` are not `constexpr` according to the C++ standard. So, really, your code should simply never work. It appears `strncmp` is a GCC/Clang magic builtin, so that's probably why all the weird behavior is happening (but your compiler is actually buggy for ever letting any of your examples compile).

Write your own `strncmp` that is `constexpr`. Also, mark `STRINGS` as `constexpr` (see confusion in comments).

Comment: Indeed, it is likely a bug in GCC. `strncmp` is not `constexpr`, it shouldn't be allowed in a constexpr function.

Comment: @user17732522 Actually, I'm thinking that's not necessary. The thing passed as template parameter is not the object (`STRINGS`) itself, but the address of its first element, and the code within the function again doesn't read any of the arrays in `STRINGS`, but their elements. And static-lifetime scalar constants do not need `constexpr` to be usable under `constexpr`, while dealing with addresses in `constexpr` only requires static lifetime and not the objects being `constexpr`. But marking `STRINGS` as `constexpr` would be clarifying to the reader.

Comment: @user17732522 No, `T[i]` is itself an array, to which lvalue-to-rvalue conversion cannot be applied. Instead, *array-to-pointer* conversion (decay) is applied, which doesn't require the object `T[i]` to be usable in constant expressions. And subobjects of string literals (the actual `char`s of `STRINGS`) are usable in constant expressions automatically regardless of being marked `constexpr`.

Comment: @HTNW I think you are right. I did not think about this clearly.

Comment: @HTNW However, the access to the `const char` objects inside `strncmp` wouldn't be to elements of the string literal, but the nested array, and the exceptional rule not requiring `constexpr` for _usable in constant expressions_ applies only to _variables_ that are of `const` non-`volatile` integral/enumeration type, not _any_ object or arrays thereof and _usable in constant expressions_ applies to subobjects only if the parent object is _usable in constant expressions_. So accessing the `const char` elements of the 2D array would not be covered: https://godbolt.org/z/q1f1r7sdW

Comment: @user17732522 Hm, perhaps you're right.